# Обработка изображения с помощью OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, captcha

Стоит задача распознавания [капчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0) с некоторого ресурса.

Капча, как мне кажется, простая в плане распознавания, т.к. в ней только одни цифры, которые не искажены, а немного могут быть повернуты под углом.

Исходное изображение в оттенках серого.

Проблема в том, что не понятно как произвести предобработку изображения перед распознавание.

Например, как привести изображение к бинарному виду (чёрный фон, белые символы или наоборот)?

Использую *OpenCV*

[image: Пример исходного изображения]
[image: Пример исходного изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легко от фона не избавитесь, чтобы оставить одни цифры. 
Делайте так:

- Canny
- findContours
- цикл по контурам с целью избавиться от контуров, которые примыкают к
  краям, или слишком широкие, или содержат вертикальные или
  горизонтальные прямые линии.
- в оставшихся контурах останутся контуры символов с незначительными
  примесями, можно их например нарисовать черным на белом (drawConrours) сделать erode и отправить OCR

Отфильтровать контуры будет самое сложное, я для примера набросал, а на самом деле надо будет поотлаживать - возможно даже выбрасывать где-то не целые контуры а фрагменты - есть где развернуться творчеству.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Буду пробывать